# How can I send data together with flask response object?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

This is my code for sending data:

```
@app.route('/testColoring')
def testColoring():
     ...
     return jsonify({'image_url': imgPath})
```

However, I would like to send it as a Response object, because I want to set the headers to disable cache. Something like this:

```
response = make_response()
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
```

At first, I thought it would be response.data, but according to the [flask API documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#response-objects) it should not be used and it will be deprecated.

Please advise on how I could combine response and json data, or other possible solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Jsonify already returns a Response object.

Answer (score 1):

[`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.json.jsonify) returns a response object.  Instead of returning it directly, set a variable and modify the headers before returning.

```
rv = jsonify(data)
rv.headers.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate')
return rv
```